# Syntax highlighting inside Symfony annotations in Sublime 3

Tags: symfony, annotations, sublimetext3

Is there any plugin for sublime that is adding color highlight to the Symfony annotations for PHP? Or is it easy to add in some other way? Even if the annotations are written as PHP comments, it would be nice to have some color there as well.

Answer (score 0):

There is no plugin at the moment, but I found an [interesting Gist](https://gist.github.com/krisrybak/ba7a9da1b80be6c913c9) with instructions to change the default PHP syntax highlighting in order to support the Symfony, Doctrine and JMS annotations.

These are the dict patterns that you should add for the PHP document:

```
    <dict>
        <key>match</key>
        <string>\@(Route|Template|Method|ParamConverter|Cache)\b</string>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>keyword.other.symfonyannotations.php</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>match</key>
        <string>\@(Assert)\b</string>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>keyword.other.symfonyassertannotations.php</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>match</key>
        <string>\@(ORM)\b</string>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>keyword.other.doctrineannotations.php</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>match</key>
        <string>\@(Secure)\b</string>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>keyword.other.jmssecurityannotations.php</string>
    </dict>
```

See the Gist for detailed instructions

*(Note: I personally didn't try it yet, but looks fine to me)*